# No italic correction in math mode?

Tags: italic-correction

Is it possible to get italic correction work in math mode?

I found that F or C followed by a `\forall` extremely ugly in TeX/LaTeX, and
inserting `\/` like `F \/ \forall` does not help.

Is `F \, \forall` the recommended solution?  Or is it possible to use a mechanism
similar to italic correction in text mode?

Comment: There is no italic correction in math mode, since `$f$` is not italics. Also, `\forall` is just a symbol that translates to `for all` rather than it being an operator that acts on certain operands (left and/or right). So, the spacing is ultimately up to you.

Comment: I don't know if it would help you but you can rotate a capital a upside down with $\rotatebox{180}{A}$.

Comment: @hkviktor - How exactly might rotating the letter "A" 180 degrees help with kerning?

Comment: @Werner I understand that `\forall` is not an operator, but the F touches the `\forall` that follows, which I found ugly.

Comment: @TonyBetaLambda I usually write `\forall` after a comma and a space, the space is usually a normal space `\ ` or a `\enskip` (half of an `\quad`) in *inline* math and a full `\quad` in *display* math. E.g., `$\forall x \in \mathbb{C}, \enskip \exists \alpha_0 > 1$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there is no italic correction in math-mode. There may be fonts which provide a better kerning in this case and of course, you could ask the maintainer of your font to include kerning pairs for `C\forall` and `F\forall`.

But actually I would not recommend that as it gets difficult to read if set too close together. I would treat `\forall` like a real word and therefore write something like `$C\ \forall\ x$`.

If you want to have some special kerning different to your proposed `\,` you might use my following MWE. Of course, you could define macros for often used combinations (`\newcommand*{\Cforall}{C\,\forall}`) or define your own `\forall` (`\newcommand*{\myForall}{\,\forall\,}`). The last option is quite similar to what the command `\in` is producing...

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $C\forall x$\\
    $C\,\forall\,x$\\
    $C\mkern4mu\forall\mkern4mu x$\\
    $C\ \forall\ x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An off-topic: how are these nice figures generated?

Comment: @TonyBetaLambda I used the package `lua-visual-debug` for this.